# How to include data-zoom-image in my image_tag on ruby rails 4.3.4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get my images to zoom in on my website.

I have added

```
gem 'elevatezoom-rails'
```

to my GEMFILE,

I have also added

```
$("#zoom_01").elevateZoom();
```

to my application.js file

I am just abit confused due to being a new use on where to add
    **data-zoom-image="images/large/image1.jpg**

In the code below:

```
  <div class="sub-title"> 
    <% if not @product.img_url.blank? %>
      <%= link_to (image_tag @product.img_url, size: "200x250")
          products_path, :title => 'return to "all" products ...' %> 
    <% else %>
      <%= image_tag "no-image.jpg", :size => "200x250" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Comment: the same way you added `size`, look, `image_tag` takes two arguments, the first one is the path to the image, and the second one is a Hash. So, in the second argument you can pass as many `key: value` pairs as you want, and those can be HTML attributes, so, simple add: `data-zoom-image: "your zoom image path"`.

Comment: thanks for you help much appreciated, I tried adding it in to the below and had no luck, I am not using direct img url's, please check below  `<div class="sub-title"> 
        <% if not @product.img_url.blank? %>
          <%= link_to (image_tag @product.img_url, size: "200x250", data-zoom-image: "@product.img_url")
              products_path, :title => 'return to "all" products ...' %>` @fanta

Comment: interpolation: "#{@product.img_url}"

Comment: Thanks for your help but still does not work, must be an issue with my website. `div class="sub-title"> 
        <% if not @product.img_url.blank? %>
          <%= link_to (image_tag @product.img_url, size: "200x250", data-zoom-image: "@product.img_url"),
              products_path, :title => 'return to "all" products ...' %> 
        <% else %>
          <%= image_tag "no-image.jpg", :size => "200x250" %>
        <% end %>
      </div> `

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, but maybe this is useful for some. The dashes (-) need to be changed to underscores (_). You then also won't need the quotation marks. Use:

```
<%= link_to (image_tag (@product.img_url, size: "200x250", data_zoom_image: @product.img_url)) %>
```